# Блокировка сигналов в очереди

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Есть набор кнопок, при нажатии которых  выполнятся слот:

```
void uRent::s1(const QString &i)
{
     QString line = ui->lineEdit->text();
     index = line.indexOf('_');
     line.replace(index, 1, i);
     ui->lineEdit->setText(line);
     QTimer* btimer = new QTimer(this);
     btimer->setSingleShot(true);
     btimer->setInterval(200);
     connect(btimer, &QTimer::timeout, [this, btimer](){
         QString line = ui->lineEdit->text();
         line.replace(index, 1, '*');
         ui->lineEdit->setText(line);
         btimer->deleteLater();
     });
     btimer->start();
}
```

Как можно увидеть при выполнении слота формируется сигнал таймера и который вызывает другую функцию(слот) для выполнения. В общем все работает неплохо, но при быстром нажатии кнопок сигнал таймера не успевает обрабатываться и как бы проскакивает. Видимо сигнал полученный от нажатия кнопки стает в очереди сигналов перед сигналом таймера. Как можно очистить очередь или поставить блок сигналов до выполнения слота таймера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку предполагается множество быстрых кликов, то использование `QTimer` может оказаться чрезмерным. Впрочем, если сделать его членом класса, активировать и останавливать без удаления объекта, то потери будут несущественны. Тем не менее, можно рассмотреть подход с таймером низкого уровня (в контексте Qt):

```
class uRent : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit uRent(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
            : QObject(parent), _timer_id(0), _index(-1) {}

        virtual ~uRent() {}

        void s1(const QString &i);

    protected:
        virtual void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);

    private:
        int _timer_id, _index;

    private slots:
        void onReplace();

};

void uRent::s1(const QString &i) {
    if(_timer_id > 0) {
        killTimer(_timer_id);
        _timer_id = 0;
        onReplace();
    }

    QString line = ui->lineEdit->text();
    _index = line.indexOf('_');
    if(_index == -1) return;

    line.replace(_index, 1, i);
    ui->lineEdit->setText(line);

    _timer_id = startTimer(200);
}

void uRent::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) {
    if(event->timerId() == _timer_id) {
        killTimer(_timer_id);
        _timer_id = 0;
        onReplace();
    }
}

void uRent::onReplace() {
    ui->lineEdit->setText(ui->lineEdit->text().replace(_index, 1, '*'));
}
```

Каждый новый клик будет останавливать предыдущий таймер, если тот не успел сработать, проделывать запланированную работу немедленно, ну и напоследок - запускать новый таймерный цикл.